# JobScheduler.schedule(job) is not starting the JobService

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am using a [lib](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat) for JobScheduler to work on pre-lollipop devices.I am using a lollipop device.The problem is mJobScheduler.schedule(job) should start my jobservice but it is not starting. Also when i include the .setPeriodic(2000) method the app crashes with this

stack trace.

```
08-06 00:37:06.729 19693-19693/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: rishabh.example.com.myapplication, PID: 19693
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rishabh.example.com.myapplication/rishabh.example.com.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't call setOverrideDeadline() on a periodic job.
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't call setOverrideDeadline() on a periodic job.
                                                   at me.tatarka.support.job.JobInfo$Builder.build(JobInfo.java:477)
                                                   at rishabh.example.com.myapplication.MainActivity.constructJob(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                   at rishabh.example.com.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

MY MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

JobScheduler mJobScheduler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mJobScheduler=JobScheduler.getInstance(this);
    constructJob();
}

private void constructJob() {

    JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(0 /*jobid*/, new ComponentName(this,MyService.class))
            .setMinimumLatency(1000)
            .setOverrideDeadline(2000)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setPeriodic(2000)
            .build();



    mJobScheduler.schedule(job);

}
}
```

MyService class

```
public class MyService extends JobService {
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onStartjob",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("tag","onstartjob");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}
}
```

My manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="rishabh.example.com.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true">

    </service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use both `setPeriodic()` and `setOverrideDeadline()`.

> Because it doesn't make sense setting this property on a periodic job, doing so will throw an IllegalArgumentException when build() is called.

See: [JobInfo.Builder javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setOverrideDeadline(long))

Comment: ok i removed setOverrideDeadline() property, and the app runs without error but the onStartJob() method is still not called! @koral

Comment: It seems that there is a similar [unresolved issue](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat/issues/36) with that library. Project is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat#jobschedulercompat) so it may be never fixed.

Comment: i want to perform a task for every 5 sec.what is the alternative to this? @koral

Comment: For such small intervals [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) should be appropriate. See [A flowchart for background work, alarms, and your Android app
Pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/GdNrQciPwqo)

Comment: i found this GCM network manager [https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager] how is this in comparison?

Comment: You need a server (or cloud service account) for GCM (or its successor - FCM) to work and device need working network connection. It is intended to trigger action when push message arrives (usually after entering new content on CMS connected with GCM) not for repeated work.